# Page getting reloading even after I am using jQuery on submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This is index page:

```
<?php
       // Initialize variables to null.
         $nameError ="";
          $emailError ="";
             $genderError ="";
              $websiteError ="";
             // On submitting form below function will execute.


       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
          $nameError = "Name is required";
         } else {
         $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
         // check name only contains letters and whitespace
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
      }
         }

          if (empty($_POST["lastname"])) {
         $nameError = "Name is required";
       } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
        // check name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
          $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
         }
     }



        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
       $emailError = "Email is required";
     } else {
      $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address syntax is valid or not
     if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
       $emailError = "Invalid email format";
   }
         }


       if (empty($_POST["phonenumber"])) {
     $nameError = "phone number is required";
                     } else {
    $name1 = test_input($_POST["phonenumber"]);
      // check name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]*$/",$name1)) {
      $phoneerror = "Only numbers and white space allowed";
       }
     }

        if (empty($_POST["section"])) {
         $selectError = "Choose the required field";
    } else {
          $select = test_input($_POST["section"]);
       }


          if (empty($_POST["section1"])) {
         $selectError = "Choose the required field";
         } else {
         $select = test_input($_POST["section1"]);
       }
        }

           function test_input($data) {
          $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
          }
       ?>

       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
         <title>Job Test</title>
         <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">               </script>
       <script src = "script1.js"></script>

       </head>
       <body>
       <div class="maindiv">
       <div class="form_div">
        <div class="title">
       <h2>Find Out More About Computing</h2>
        </div>

       <form method="post" action="index.php">
         Name: <br />
        <input class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" required                  placeholder="Enter name">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameError;?></span>
        <br />
       Last Name: <br />
        <input class="input" name="lastname" type="text" value="" required              placeholder="Enter  last name">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameError;?></span>
              <br />
        E-mail: <br />
      <input class="input" name="email" type="text" value=""  required placeholder="Enter Email">
           <br />
         <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailError;?></span>
         <br />
         Mobile Phone Number: <br />
          <input class="input" name="phonenumber" type="text" value="" required placeholder="Enter  Phone Number">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo @$phoneerror;?></span>
         <br />


           Citizenship: <br />
           <select class="select"  name="section" required  >
     <option value="None" >None</option>
     <option value="Austrilian" >AUSTRALIA</option>
     <option value="india" >INDIA</option>
      <option value="others" >OTHERS</option>
        </select>         
      <span class="error">*<?php echo @$selectError;?></span>

      <br />

      Are You a Permanent Resident of Australia 
          <br />
       <select class="select"  name="section1" required  >
     <option value="None" >None</option>
     <option value="YES" >YES</option>
     <option value="NO" >NO</option>

         </select>        
      <span class="error">*<?php echo @$selectError;?></span>

       <br />


        <button class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="button" value="submit">Submit</button>
       </form>
      </div>
       </body>
         </html>
```

This is html page of the form `index.php`

This is jQuery function on submit button . not to reload the the page and directing to `submit.php`

```
      $(document).ready(function() {


         $('#submit').click(function(e){
        //  e.preventDefault();
        // var page = $(this).attr('id');
            // $('#content').location.reload('content/submit.php');
       // alert('ok');
             });


       //function submit_form()
         //{
        //   var page = $(this).attr('id');
          window.location.reload('content/submit.php');
           //}

});
```

Tthis function is not running. while i press submit button it reloads the page index.php again

submit.php

```
   <div id="content">
   <h2 style="color:#FF0000;"> Thanks For the Submission </h2> 
   </div>
```

please help me .. I am stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated this is a work test I will not code it for you but will show you where you are going wrong. First of all your index file and validation file will need to be 2 separate files. The reason for this is that we will be making an AJAX call to the validate.php  file and you want it to return a value without returning the remainder of the index page.

```js
$('#submit').click(validateData());
                            
 function httpGet(theUrl){
 //FETCH Data From Server
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl , false );
 xmlhttp.send();   
 return xmlhttp.responseText;
}
                 
                            
function validateData(){
    serverResponse="validate.php?"+httpGet$("#myForm").serialize();
    if(serverResonse=="Input Valid"){
        $("#responseDiv").html("HTML FOR SUCESSFULL VALIDATION");
         $("#formDiv").css("display","none");
      
      }else{
         $("#responseDiv").html("VALIDATION ERRORS");
        
        }
  
    $("#responseDiv").css("display","inline");
   
           
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
         <title>Job Test</title>
         <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">               </script>
       <script src = "script1.js"></script>

       </head>
       <body>
        
       <div class="maindiv">
         <div id="responseDiv"></div>
       <div id="formDiv" class="form_div">
        <div class="title">
       <h2>Find Out More About Computing</h2>
        </div>

       <form id='myForm'>
         Name: <br />
        <input class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" required                  placeholder="Enter name">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameError;?></span>
        <br />
       Last Name: <br />
        <input class="input" name="lastname" type="text" value="" required              placeholder="Enter  last name">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameError;?></span>
              <br />
        E-mail: <br />
      <input class="input" name="email" type="text" value=""  required placeholder="Enter Email">
           <br />
         <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailError;?></span>
         <br />
         Mobile Phone Number: <br />
          <input class="input" name="phonenumber" type="text" value="" required placeholder="Enter  Phone Number">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo @$phoneerror;?></span>
         <br />


           Citizenship: <br />
           <select class="select"  name="section" required  >
     <option value="None" >None</option>
     <option value="Austrilian" >AUSTRALIA</option>
     <option value="india" >INDIA</option>
      <option value="others" >OTHERS</option>
        </select>         
      <span class="error">*<?php echo @$selectError;?></span>

      <br />

      Are You a Permanent Resident of Australia 
          <br />
       <select class="select"  name="section1" required  >
     <option value="None" >None</option>
     <option value="YES" >YES</option>
     <option value="NO" >NO</option>

         </select>        
      <span class="error">*<?php echo @$selectError;?></span>

       <br />


        < button class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="button"             value="submit">Submit</button>
       </form>
      </div>
       </body>
```

Now in your validate.php file if it returns "Input Valid" then your jquery will display the responseDiv and set its innerHTML to whatever you set as successful validation html.

Comment: its still not working bro.. and reloading itself to the same page

Comment: remove your method and action attributes from your form tag as well.

Comment: @komaldeepchahal your form submit url is the same page so your actually submitting the form to it's own url.

Comment: are you sure.. this will work??

Comment: It should. Except you also have other problems in your code. the .reload() function only accepts a true or false argument. if your trying to navigate that then you have to use .location="URL" also what is #content in your page?

Comment: it is div id="content"   .. content is that in submit.php page

Comment: @komaldeepchahal I just modified my answer. First <div> contains no location property. Second you can't address what is in your submit.php because it is not loaded into the DOM. You can only address what is on the current page.

Comment: man i am totaaly confused now.. can you please help me by coming my pc through team viewer.... i am doing this from last 10 hours.. its my job test.. please help me man .. its urgent to complete in 1 hour

Comment: Sorry man. More then happy to answer any questions on here. I'm in the middle of work myself and my rate is roughly 200 an hour.

Comment: Please edit your original post with EXACTLY what this script is supposed to accomplish. And I can have you in the right dirrection.

Comment: Are you not posting edit?

Comment: yea posting  now man

Comment: now check whole code .. what i am trying to do... i am doing validation with php  and after submitting i want it hides the form  and present thank you without reloading the page

Comment: i tried removing action and methed.. then my validation dont work

Comment: Check my revised edit. It's going to take alot of work. You attacked the entire problem wrong. The only was to do what you are wanting is to either validate entirely in javascript or make an AJAX call to your php file.

Comment: Also keep in mind the way i have shown above uses HTTP GET so you will need to change your php to $_GET

Comment: okay.. thanks .. let me try this

Comment: Okay.  Please don't forget to select this as the correct answer

Comment: okay.. sure......................

Answer (score 0):

Change your button type from:

```
<input class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit"             value="submit">
```

to

```
<button type="button" onclick="submit_form()" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

and

```
function submit_form()
{
     // var page = $(this).attr('id');
     window.location.reload('content/submit.php');
}
```

Comment: Don't forget type="button" several browsers default type="submit" on all buttons located inside of a form.

Comment: still not working man,.

Comment: See what I've modified.

Comment: ok let me check this also

Comment: Try again...I change `$('#content')` to `window`

Comment: can you come on pc teamviewer.. i need ur help

Comment: Just try the last code I've modified.

Comment: ok let me check it again

Comment: still not working with it

Comment: remove `var page = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: what will happen with this

Comment: no still not working

Comment: man please come on my pc... its my job test... i would really thankful if you help me in this. and can could do it faster

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your submit button:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#content').location.reload('content/submit.php');

});
```

This code "e.preventDefault()" try to stop default function on the submit button. Hope it works.

Comment: do i need to remove form action and methed ???

Comment: no not working..............